# Get all top categories, then only 3 posts for each

Tags: database, performance

I'm building a custom homepage that has that structure:

### Cat 1

Post 1 | Post 2 | Post 3

### Cat 1

Post 1 | Post 2 | Post 3

etc...

I know how to get all top non-empty categories, loop through them and inside each fetch latest 3 posts. However, that would imply doing as many exdtra DB queries as categories I have, so I think that would not be optimal.

I think I might be able to hack a custom SQL query that fetches that data only, but I want to be able to use recular post code such as `<?php the_permalink(); ?>`.

Is there an optimal solution to this?

Comment: For relatively expensive queries like this you can always cache the results for a few hours using [the Transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API), so it shouldn't add too much load to the database. However I'm not sure you can easily mix that with the regular PHP calls you're asking for.

Comment: When you say top, do you mean the most popular, the largest, or those categories that don't have parents? An SQL query shouldn't be needed for this

Comment: @TomJNowell I mean categories without parents.